# Kibana 4 "rehash": false

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm using Kibana 4 to query unique count on ElasticSearch.

I would like to [prevent rehash on field,](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#CO22-2) since the field is already hashed.

How can I make Kibana to perform the aggregation using `"rehash": false`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible, and since the `cardinality-aggregation` feature is defined as an experimental feature, I believe the team working on kibana will wait to see what happens with this in elasticsearch before implementing a UI for this in kibana, if at all.